WalletConnect and useWallet but its returning null value
I created a simple wallet connect application. I'm trying to show a form after geting the wallet address but its always showing the publicKey value as null. Wallet is successfully connected and I'm able to print that on the UI but when I try to use that for another form/button its showing as "wallet is not connected"
I tried to connect over console and it is successfull. Below is successfully returning the wallet address but I was not able to get the address from frontend.
window.solana.connect()
window.solana.publicKey.toString()

Here is my code
App.js:
import React from "react";
import { WalletConnect, WalletInfo } from "./components/WalletConnect";
import TitleForm from "./components/TitleForm";
import { WalletMultiButton } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
import { useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";

function App() {
  const { publicKey } = useWallet(); 

  // logs -- here I can not get the wallet address!
  console.log("publicKey from useWallet:", publicKey ? publicKey.toString() : "null");
  console.log("connected from useWallet:", connected);

  return (
    <WalletConnect>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "20px" }}>
        <h1>Phantom Wallet Uygulaması</h1>
        <WalletMultiButton />
        <WalletInfo />
        {publicKey ? (
          <>
            <p>Wallet address (Here is working fine address is there): {publicKey.toString()}</p>
            <TitleForm walletAddress={publicKey.toString()} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <p>Wallet is not connected. Please connect your wallet.</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </WalletConnect>
  );
}

export default App;


walletconnect.js
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-phantom";
import { WalletModalProvider } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
import { useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css";

export const WalletConnect = ({ children }) => {
  const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;
  const endpoint = "https://api.devnet.solana.com"; 

  const wallets = useMemo(() => [new PhantomWalletAdapter()], []); /

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>{children}</WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
};

